# We need a plain HTTP download for the Trilogy data dump

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, data-dump

Now that net neutrality is gone and Comcast and it's ilk are beginning to throttle BitTorrent, we should have a "legal" way to download the data dump.

I know there's third-party hosts, but they're often outdated and prone to 404ing.  Why can't we have a plain ol' HTTP release?

Comment: Are you going to pay for the bandwidth? We're talking 700mb per download, and rising. Not that I totally disagree...

Comment: How can a *protocol* be illegal?

Comment: @Downvoter: Ask the US government.

Comment: @Downvoter: ask fibertel. They told me they were filtering it for "security reasons". To my surprise Telefónica has a great service.

Comment: It's not how, it's what. Anyway, there are ways to circumvent technical barriers @voy, we are geeks after all... I use my full bandwidth with fibertel.

Comment: @Downvoter: not when they don't send their technicians for 2 moths, leaving me without a connection because they had issued a wrong impedance connector, and the whole block had problems but I were the only one complaining, so they assumed it was a problem with viruses. On my Debian box. *sigh* I'll be happy if I never have to deal with their half-brained tech support. *No sir, we don't support SSH connections. So you are running the Linux application? Have you tried uninstalling it and trying again?*

Comment: @Downvoter: a protocol can be illegal if its use is prohibited by the law. In order to do that the protocol itself doesn't need to be evil; the fact that it can be used for malicious purposes is usually sufficient. See for example guns; how can guns be illegal? They don't harm anyone as long as you don't use them to shoot people. Same for bittorrent; it doesn't hurt anyone if used for legal purposes, but it has the potential to be misused, and thus is/will be/can be/might be illegal.

Comment: @Kop: are guns illegal?

Comment: @voyager: in many countries, including mine, yes.

Answer (score 4):

I have a little archive of data dumps [here](http://tejp.de/files/so/dbdump/) and usually also put new ones there rather fast.

But on the other hand the torrents are also well seeded and much more fail safe, so it really makes sense to download the data by bittorrent. That Comcast does stupid things doesn't mean that suddenly bittorrent as a distribution service is broken. It means that Comcast broke their own internet service, but this is all the problem of Comcast and their customers. If the customers don't like that they should complain to Comcast or change their service provider.

Thinking about it, maybe I should remove the data dump files from my server.

Comment: Wow. I've been looking for this old data for several days. ClearBits disappeared, the other HTTP mirror was shut down, and there are no peers on BitTorrent for several of them. I was just about to make a post asking if the data was lost forever when I came across theis post. I'm grateful that, in the end, you didn't decide to remove the data dump files from your server. Thanks!

Comment: @JeremyBanks: I have added some more dumps that were on the server but not linked in that directory. So in case also need something from from 2010-09 to 2012-08 it's now downloadable. (There isn't a dump for every month, but I'm pretty sure it's everything that was released in that time frame).

Comment: Beautiful, thanks again. I didn't even realize that the pre-ClearBits data dumps were released as torrents, and now I have those too. One funny thing: I notice that the for oldest dump, May 2009, you have a torrent for a .ZIP file, but the data in a .7Z file. If you remember: were the dumps released in both formats, and you just happened to download a non-matching pair?

Comment: (Nevermind; the torrent used the 7Z file, but just had it mis-named as a ZIP file.)

Answer (score 3):

Look, I'm aware that in several places there are large ISP that don't give a rat's ass about their customers, and that filter everything non HTTP (and sometimes even that), but it's not SO's fault, it's your ISP's.

I live in a city that has at most 5 big providers, 3 of which only resell the other 2 pipes. The provider I used to have is like Comcast, only that with another name, After 6 months of taking their abuse, I just changed for a telcom ADSL provider and haven't looked back. They understand *a bit* better that they are *supposed to be* dumb pipes.

You wouldn't ask So to be available on Gopher only because your ISP is blocking HTTP, would you?

Answer (score 2):

What isn't legal about http://clearbits.com and the torrent protocol?

There are usually http mirrors contributed by other users within a few hours of the torrent being posted.

As always see

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/

For the latest information on the data dumps.

Comment: Comcast filtering bittorret had nothing to do about legality.

Answer (score 2):

I assume the barrier to this is the enormous amount of bandwidth needed to support such a download.

Instead of putting the load directly on one server, using BitTorrent, it's distributed over the community at large.

Yes, some ISPs are throttling BitTorrent, which is unfortunate because it's a completely legal method to download and share files. The whole issue surrounds the *content* of the files. Since ISPs would be sued into the stone age if they started filtering content, they chose to do something about the protocol instead, and that, of course, is a hot topic of debate.

That being said, even if an ISP is throttling your bandwidth to, say, 20 kb/s at all hours of the day, the data dump can be downloaded in less than half a day. For anyone wanting to download this stuff, it's not a big deal to leave your computer on overnight.

I would say that an official HTTP host of this content is unnecessary, although certainly not undesirable if it were available. And as Jeff mentions, users are free to host the files however they want after an original copy is obtained.

Alternate solution: PayPal me $5 and I'll send you a copy on a DVD. :)

Comment: I had a ISP (Fibertel, something like the local Comcast) sending RST responses to both parties of any bittorrent connection within seconds of it being established. I got .2kbps for any given torrent. I can understand this guy's feelings, but the one at fault is his ISP.

Comment: @voyager: Yeah, for sure. Every ISP does it differently, too, so it's kind of case-dependent. One of the ISPs here caps at 20-something kb/s in core usage hours. I think that for internet power users who would be downloading a data dump, it is less likely they would be on a throttled connection (unless there is literally zero choice), so I'm assuming this is a very small minority problem.

Comment: Copy on a dvd is not a bad idea. (not that i'm gona order one). Maybe stackoverflow should make it official