# How to download a data-dump of stackoverflow data set?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I need a fresh copy of stackoverflow datasets.  I want to download it but unfortunately I can not use torrents in my university LAN. Are they available in any other way? i.e. downloadable via HTTP?

Comment: [Non-BitTorrent way to get the Stack Overflow Creative Commons Data Dump?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3764)

Answer (score 1):

There is an [HTTP Version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48120/we-need-a-plain-http-download-for-the-trilogy-data-dump/48124#48124) of the dumps that have been provided by @sth.  In case that post goes missing somehow, [here's the link](http://tejp.de/files/so/dbdump/).  These files are not provided by Stackoverflow directly, and I've never used them, so I can't say much about their validity.

EDIT

Those links appear to only be older dumps. The newer dumps are [located here](http://media10.simplex.tv/content/xtendx/stu/stackoverflow/). This infrmation has been taken from [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3764/non-bittorrent-way-to-get-the-stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/31225#31225).